# R Refer to (part of) data frame using string in R

Tags: r

I have a large data set in which I have to search for specific codes depending on what i want. For example, chemotherapy is coded by ~40 codes, that can appear in any of 40 columns called (diag1, diag2, etc).

I am in the process of writing a function that produces plots depending on what I want to show. I thought it would be good to specify what I want to plot in a input data frame. Thus, for example, in case I only want to plot chemotherapy events for patients, I would have a data frame like this:

```
Dataframe name: Style
 Name   SearchIn                                codes         PlotAs  PlotColour
 Chemo  data[substr(names(data),1,4)=="diag"]  1,2,3,4,5,6     |       red
```

I already have a function that searches for codes in specific parts of the data frame and flags the events of interest. ***What i cannot do, and need your help with, is referring to a data frame (Style$SearchIn[1]) using codes in a data frame as above.***

```
> Style$SearchIn[1]
[1] data[substr(names(data),1,4)=="diag"]
Levels:  data[substr(names(data),1,4)=="diag"]
```

I thought perhaps get() would work, but I cant get it to work:

```
> get(Style$SearchIn[1])
Error in get(vars$SearchIn[1]) : invalid first argument
enter code here
```

or

```
> get(as.character(Style$SearchIn[1]))
Error in get(as.character(Style$SearchIn[1])) :   
object 'data[substr(names(data),1,5)=="TDIAG"]' not found
```

Obviously, running *data[substr(names(data),1,5)=="TDIAG"]* works.

Example:

```
  library(survival)
  ex <- data.frame(SearchIn="lung[substr(names(lung),1,2) == 'ph']")

  lung[substr(names(lung),1,2) == 'ph'] #works
  get(ex$SearchIn[1]) # does not work
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I disagree, I don't think this question is poorly written. The OP is just wrestling with a design issue, and trying to use data.frames and dynamic logic in inadvisable ways. I think the overall intention of the question is clear.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a good idea to store R code in strings and then try to eval them when needed; there are nearly always better solutions for dynamic logic, such as lambdas.

I would recommend using a list to store the plot specification, rather than a data.frame. This would allow you to include a function as one of the list's components which could take the input data and return a subset of it for plotting.

For example:

```
library(survival);

plotFromSpec <- function(data,spec) {
    filteredData <- spec$filter(data);
    ## ... draw a plot from filteredData and other stuff in spec ...
};

spec <- list(
    Name='Chemo',
    filter=function(data) data[,substr(names(data),1,2)=='ph'],
    Codes=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
    PlotAs='|',
    PlotColour='red'
);
plotFromSpec(lung,spec);
```

If you want to store multiple specifications, you could create a list of lists.

Comment: This is an interesting idea... The potential problem with this is that I can have dozens of things to include, and it might vary from 1 project to another. I guess i can have a list of each of the items, and combine lists in order to make the complete specs list...

Comment: EDIT (10 mins later) mmmm I am struggling how to use this approach with multiple specs (e.g chemo, surgery, radiotherapy)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `quote()`

I'm not entirely sure what you want but maybe you could store the things you're trying to `get()` like

```
quote(data[substr(names(data),1,4)=="diag"])
```

and then use `eval()`

```
eval(quote(data[substr(names(data),1,4)=="diag"]), list(data=data))
```

For example,

```
dat <- data.frame("diag1"=1:10, "diag2"=1:10, "other"=1:10)
Style <- list(SearchIn=c(quote(data[substr(names(data),1,4)=="diag"]), quote("Other stuff")))

> head(eval(Style$SearchIn[[1]], list(data=dat)))
  diag1 diag2
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     3     3
4     4     4
5     5     5
6     6     6
```

Comment: Its not 'data[substr(names(data),1,4)=="diag"]' that doesnt work, it is Style$SearchIn[1], that doesnt work. quote(Style$SearchIn[1]) doesn't help me.Thnx

Comment: @Luc You would need to quote the `data[...]` and `eval()` the Style$SearchIn[1]

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand. Can you write it out?

Comment: @Luc I added an example